# Https Website using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, https, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I have a question regarding using an `HttpUrlConnection` with a https web service.

Basically, we had previously written a bunch of web services to be used in an Android application that were all http calls. We want to change those over to use https instead. Basically, what I'm concerned with, is will my existing code work properly? I had previously created a connection like the following:

```
HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
myConnection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
myConnection.connect();
```

This appears to be working fine with the new https web services, but I'm wondering why I don't need to change it to something like this:

```
HttpsURLConnection myConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
myConnection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
myConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(createSSLSocketFactory());
myConnection.connect();
```

I'm still planning on moving to a `HttpsURLConnection` instead, but I'm curious how older versions of our app will be affected by our intended changes.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In docs for [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) you will find:

> Calling openConnection() on a URL with the "https" scheme will return
>   an HttpsURLConnection

But since HttpsUrlConnection extends from HttpUrlConnection, this code:

```
HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
```

will NOT result in class cast exception if url is for https connection. You still can cast to HttpsUrlConnection - just for safety you can check with `instanceof` if url scheme should change.

Comment: This is totally what I expected to happen, but for some reason it isn't, and it still appears to work despite the URL change... I don't know if there's any chance the WS isn't a 'true' https web service but now i'm just totally speculating.

Comment: as a tip, with AndroidStudio you can actually step into the `Net.newConnection()` to see what it actually does.

Comment: Nice, thanks for much for your help. I'll be pushing out an update but happy to know I won't need to force an update on older app version users.